# EWS code and Email Signatures

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

At the moment i'm currently using using `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data` library to read email addresses and send to a database. However, i'm having troubles as i currently want to loop through the attachments of a single email but exclude any attachments (images) that are included in the signature of the email.

I can get the non embedded images by

```
if (emailMessage.HasAttachments)
{
    foreach (FileAttachment fileAttachments in emailMessage.Attachments)
    {

        FileAttachment fileAttachment = emailMessage.Attachments[i.Attachments.IndexOf(fileAttachments)] as FileAttachment;
        fileAttachment.Load();

        if (!fileAttachment.IsInline)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

but is there a way to get embedded images that are not included in the signature?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do reverse of what is done in this example http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/createinlineattachment.html

Check ContentId property value on FileAttachment and check if the same value exists in the message body. These images are not part of the email signature.